# How to set a border for UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a view which consists of one UITableView and one `UIScrollView`, now I need to draw a **border** for the `UITableView` so that it can be isolated from the `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 19):

Check out UIView **layer** property which allows you to define visible border for the view. Try out the following:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

...

```
self.yourtableview.layer.borderWidth = 2;
self.yourtableview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

Also remember to include QuartzCore.framework in your project Frameworks list.

Comment: hi Ari j.R i tried using it but its throwing the error as fallows even though i had added the framework..."request for member'layer'is something not a structure or union.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to set the table boarder.

1.You just add the `UIView` whose size is little larger than table view.
Add the table view as a subview of the view.

As, if table view frame size is (2,2,100, 200), then the view size should be (0,0,104,204).

2.Set the `backgroundColor` of the view as you want to set for the border color.